# Remove Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from a desktop computer

Tags: 14.04

I was given a computer with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on it. I am not familiar with this system and it will not support a device that i would like to connect to the computer and use. I want to remove the Ubuntu so that i can install windows. When I put in the windows disc nothing happens so i have read that i need to remove Ubuntu first.  I have no idea at all how to do this. Can someone please give me the step by step to remove it. I greatly appreciate anyones help. I have never removed software but was so thankful to be given the computer that i have so i need to get windows on it so that I can use it. Thanks!

Comment: Simple. Install Windows. That will remove Ubuntu. You almost certainly need to open the BIOS, and set your boot order appropriately (and that's not really about Ubuntu).

Comment: Well how do I install Windows when i put in the install disc and nothing pops up to install? I don't know how Ubuntu works. On windows you can click on my computer to open the disc you put in but with Ubuntu nothing is happening.  Also I have no idea what BIOS is. I have never dealt with boot order just basic windows and microsoft office. I appreciate any help you can dumb down for me.

Comment: The windows version I have is XP could that be the problem?

Comment: Well, I was criticized for making this an answer, so I'll make it a comment. Your computer should (might) have an instruction on the startup screen telling you what function key to hit in order to get to the boot menu. Put your Windows disk in, restart your computer, and press that function key as soon as the startup screen appears. Keep pressing it until the boot menu shows up. You should be given the option to boot from the CD/DVD drive. Select that option and that should begin the Windows installation process.

Comment: @AlcuinArundel just in case the computer doesn't say, the most common keys that go to the setup are Esc, F1, F2, F10, F12, and Del.

Comment: Well, I pressed the function key and no option was given to boot from CD/DVD drive.  Thank you all for your help I tried but I can't figure it out. I think it is a lot more complicated than I am capable of.  Have a good night.  :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to simple install Windows following the normal procedure.  This will typically involve placing the installation disc in the drive and setting your computer to boot from this drive (this is dependent on your motherboard, but may involve pressing F12, F2, or DEL during initial boot first, then selecting the CD/DVD drive as first boot device).

There is no need to "uninstall" the previous operating system, and Ubuntu does not support such an action.

The normal method for completely replacing the previous operating system is using the installation procedure for the new operating system, and when prompted, tell it to utilise the entire hard drive for the new system, which will result in the loss of the old operating system.

Comment: I'm done. I don't know how to boot from a drive and i sure don't know what the motherboard is.  All i know is I put the windows disc in and nothing happened. I went to the system files and when i clicked on disc drive nothing happened. I tried putting the windows disc in and restarting and pressing the F12 and a bunch of stuff came up that i didn't know about. I guess i won't be getting windows on this computer after all. At least I can use it for Internet but that is about it. Thanks again everyone for trying to help me.

Comment: You were almost there. When you hit F12 and a "bunch of stuff came up," that was probably the boot menu. You could have just cursored down to the CD/DVD entry and hit enter, and you'd now be installing your Windows OS. Sorry to see you give up.

Answer (score 0):

1. See what shows on your first screen when you start your computer. it would say press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, or <kbd>Del</kbd> or something to enter setup. It is fast, you have to focus on your screen. If it doesn't show that, try to press these keys fast.

   My picture shows to press <kbd>Del</kbd> at the buttom of screen.

   [image: screenshot of POST message]
2. find the option called "boot" or "boot priority". Choose the first one, press enter or something, change it to CD/DVD. My example is boot from USB.

   [image]
3. The most important thing is remember to "save & exit", you must find this, and choose it.

   Sorry, I'm a new user of this web site. I'm not allowed to add more than 2 pictures before I get 10 reputations or something. And I'm not an English speaker, if you don't understand my sentences tell me.

   So, you have to on your own to finish the 3rd step. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

First put the disc in the drive and shut off the computer. Now, turn it back on and press the key to enter boot menu. It is different for most PC brands, for example on most Dell computers the key is F12, but it should show up on the first screen once you press the power button. When on the first screen, press that key a lot until you get to the menu. Now, use the arrow keys to navigate to something like CD-ROM drive. Press Enter and now the computer should be booting from the disc.

Hope I helped!